# Tornado end points

Tags: python, rest, tornado, endpoints

I am experimenting with Tornado and wasnt sure how to support two different REST API end points. Say I want to support "/" and "/Hello". Based on initial documentation I came up with this, do I need to create a handler class for each end point?

```
import tornado.ioloop
import tornado.web

class MainHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    self.write("Hello, Tornado")

class SecondHandler(tornado.web.RequestHandler):
  def get(self):
    self.write("<em>Hello, Second Handler!</em>")

def make_app():
  return tornado.web.Application([
    (r"/", MainHandler),
    (r"/Hello", SecondHandler)
  ])

if __name__ == "__main__":
  app = make_app()
  app.listen(8888)
  tornado.ioloop.IOLoop.current().start()
```

Answer (score 1):

Yes, that is the correct way to implement multiple endpoints.

Comment: That was exactly what I was looking for[.](https://i.kym-cdn.com/entries/icons/original/000/026/152/gigachad.jpg)

Answer (score 1):

It is not necessary to have a separate handler for each endpoint. Practically a single RequestHandler object can serve any number of endpoints.

So it is a design decision for you, whether you want to serve multiple requests with a single RequestHandler or the way you have correctly done above.

In above case if you choose to use MainHandler for both endpoints then it will simply look like this.

```
 def make_app():   
     return tornado.web.Application([
     (r"/", MainHandler),
     (r"/Hello", MainHandler)   ])
```